# PHP Server: The MySQLi extension is not available

Tags: configuration

One Joomla instance is running in MAMP PHP 8.0 and MySql 5.7 succesfully.
When starting the same instance with a PHP Server from the `/joomla` directory like this:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t .
```

I get the `The MySQLi extension is not available` error. MAMP with MySql is still running.

This already worked a few days before. The only thing that changed was the Joomla 4.2 update.